# Cmake Unable to find the requested Boost libraries. - boost_coroutine 1.53

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Getting errors trying to build with boost on my Ubuntu x64 13.10
I installed libboost-all-dev

```
$ cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
statusCompiling on UNIX
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1126 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.53.0

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_coroutine
```

I checked to see if boost_coroutine package is installed, but there is no version 1.53

```
$ apt-cache search libboost-coroutine
libboost-coroutine1.54-dev - provides a sort of cooperative multitasking on a single thread
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `libboost-all-dev` package points to [version 1.53](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libdevel/libboost1.53-all-dev), but somehow Ubuntu 13.10 is missing the corresponding coroutine subpackage.

If you have no particular attachment to version 1.53, try installing `libboost1.54-all-dev` instead. [That package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libdevel/libboost1.54-all-dev) actually does have the coroutine subpackage available as you pointed out above, so you should at least be able to build your project.